# Freshly installed CentOS does not boot from Dell's Perc H700 RAID

Tags: centos5, boot, dell-perc, h700

Installed a fresh CentOS 5.10 installation on RAID5 provided by Perc H700 Integrated RAID, however the system fails to boot.

Checked the system via recovery CD, and noticed that CentOS 5.10 now uses GPT instead of MBR. Updated H700 to latest firmware version, same result.

Previous version of CentOS (5.x circa 2011) worked just fine on this server.

Any idea how to make the RAID recognize the partition / boot record and start the system?

Comment: Um, how large were the drives?

Comment: 3TB each, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by splitting to two VD's, one small with just enough space to contain the boot partition, and the other with the rest of partitions.